# Php Ajax file not uploaded to 000webhost database

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin

Currently I work on using php upload file to the database. So I was successful uploaded the file. In the database has show the path of the file, but I check on database the file is not there.

**Below is database data, you can see in the circle part the path is correct.**

[image]

**On below my database side don't have any file**

[image]

Below is my code, wish somebody can help me figure out where is my wrong part.

**submit.php**

```
$ideaTopic = $_POST['ideaTopic'];
$ideaCategories = $_POST['ideaCategories'];
$ideaContent = $_POST['ideaContent'];
$ideaChooseFile = $_POST['ideaChooseFile'];
$anonymous = $_POST['anonymous'];
$checkbox_term = $_POST['checkbox_term'];
$getfile = $_FILES["uploadfile"]['name'];

$complete = true;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if ($checkbox_term != "accpected") {
    $termIsNotCheck = true;
    $complete = false;
}
else{
    $termIsNotCheck = false;
}

if (empty($ideaTopic)) {
    $isEmpty_topic = true;
    $complete = false;

}
else{
    $isEmpty_topic = false;
}

if (empty($ideaCategories)) {
    $isEmpty_categories = true;
    $complete = false;

}

else{
    $isEmpty_categories = false;
}

if (empty($ideaContent)) {
    $isEmpty_content = true;
    $complete = false;

}

else{
    $isEmpty_content = false;
}

//start here

if ($_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"] == "application/pdf" ||$_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"] == "application/zip" || $_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "application/msword" ||
    $_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" )
{
//            echo"true";

        if ($_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"] > 0) {
            $complete = false;
            $error_upload_file = true;


//            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
        } else {


            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"])) {
                $file_exist = true;

//                echo $_FILES["image"]["name"] . " <span id='invalid'><b>already exists.</b></span> ";
            }
            else {
                if (!is_dir("upload/" . $u_id . "/file/")) {
                    mkdir("upload/" . $u_id . "/file/");
                }
                else {

                }

                $sourcePath = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
                $targetPath = "upload/" . $u_id . "/file/" . $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
                move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath); // Moving Uploaded file
//                echo $targetPath;


                if ($complete) {
                    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO idea (idea_topic,idea_categories,idea_content,idea_choose_file,idea_anonymous) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                        $stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $ideaTopic, $ideaCategories, $ideaContent, $targetPath, $anonymous);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();
                        $submit_successful = true;

                    } else {
                        $submit_successful = false;
                    }

                }


            }
        }

}
else{
//        echo"not imgae";
}


$idea_status = array(
    'submit-successful' => $submit_successful,
    'isEmpty-topic' => $isEmpty_topic,
    'isEmpty-categories' => $isEmpty_categories,
    'isEmpty-content' => $isEmpty_content,
    'isEmpty-choosefile' => $isEmpty_choosefile,
//        'isEmpty-closuredate' => $isEmpty_closuredate,
//        'isEmpty-finalclosure' => $isEmpty_finalclosure,
    'termIsNotCheck' => $termIsNotCheck,
    'error_upload_file' =>$error_upload_file,
    'file_exist' => $file_exist

);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($idea_status);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By moving your file, you must use the absolute not the relative path to the new file.

```
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, __DIR__."/".$targetPath);
```